# Group data with intervals in R

Tags: r, grouping, intervals

Is there a way to group data and get intervals?
For example I have a data like this (in reality I have much more longer data):

```
score        class
2,100           1
8,600           3
2,600           1
5,200           2
92,900          7
10,500          3
37,500          5
```

So I want to group by class that it would show me intervals from my data, for example:

```
class interval
1     0.1-4.3
2     4.4-7.3 etc
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where does the `0.1-4.3` come from?

Comment: do you have predetermined intervals? do you use any discretization technique? if that's the case, you can simply use cut function with breaks parameter

Comment: @Florian from the data

Comment: @boyaronur I need to get intervals from the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can get range of `score` within `class`.

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- data.frame(score = runif(10), class = sample(1:3, size = 10, replace = TRUE))
xy

aggregate(score ~ class, FUN = range, data = xy)

  class    score.1    score.2
1     1 0.22486212 0.93373648
2     2 0.05504568 0.99134086
3     3 0.74745869 0.77839970
```

Or perhaps

```
aggregate(score ~ class, data = xy, FUN = function(x) {
  paste(round(range(x), 3), collapse = " - ")
})

  class         score
1     1 0.225 - 0.934
2     2 0.055 - 0.991
3     3 0.747 - 0.778
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Easy and fast way :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your suggested results, but based on the text I suggest:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  summarise(range = paste0(min(score), " - ", max(score)))
```

output would be:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  class range        
  <int> <chr>        
1     1 2100 - 2600  
2     2 5200 - 5200  
3     3 8600 - 10500 
4     5 37500 - 37500
5     7 92900 - 92900
```

Comment: For some reason I get: NA-NA for all intervals even though I don't have NA-values in the data. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: probably the you have to run `data$score <- as.numeric(data$score)` first.

Comment: Does not really help

Comment: I assume the NA still remains? what is the output of `class(data$score)` ?

Comment: the output is `numeric`